# Evaluation of (de)reference operators

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, evaluation

I have an (uncommented...) source file which I'm trying to understand.

```
static const Map *gCurMap;
static std::vector<Map> mapVec;
```

then

```
auto e = mapVec.end();
auto i = mapVec.begin();
while(i!=e) {
    // ...
    const Map *map = gCurMap = &(*(i++));
    // ...
}
```

I don't understand what `&(*(i++))` does. It does not compile when just using `i++`, but to me it looks the same, because I'm "incrementing" `i`, then I'm requesting the value at the given address and then I'm requesting the address of this value?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at all. `&*x` is the same as `operator&(operator*(x))`, which can be anything you want.

It is only true for *pointer types* like `T * p` that `&*p` is the same as `p`. But C++ has user-defined types and overloadable operators.

The dereference operator (`*`) is typically overloaded for iterators to return a reference to the container element. The effect of the ampersand operator (`&`) on the container element is up to the class author; if you want to take the address unconditionally, you should use `std::addressof(*i++)` (from your fa­vou­rite header`<memory>`).

Answer (score 3):

`mapVec.begin()` returns an iterator which has an overloaded `operator++`. The "dereference" (overloaded `operator*`) of the iterator is to get to the `map` object. The reference `&` is, well, because `map` is a pointer, so it's being assigned to the address of the object from the dereference of `i`. We can't do simply `i++` because it would still be an iterator, and not the actual `map` object.

Answer (score 2):

`i` is an iterator, `*i` is the object pointed to by that iterator, and `&*i` is the address of that object. If the iterator were just a plain old pointer, this would be unnecessary, but usually it's not so simple. The iterator is often of some class type that overloads `operator*` to allow you to access the object it is pointing at. So this is basically a conversion from an iterator to an element to a pointer to that element.

I would move the increment to the next line because it just makes the given line harder to understand. This would be equivalent because the value of `i++` is just `i` and the increment happens afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't the same: `i` is an iterator. Dereferencing an iterator yields a reference to some object, i.e., a `T&` for some type `T`. Taking the address of such an object yields a `T*`, i.e., the address of the object at the location `i`. That the iterator is also incremented in the same expression is just a detail and likely to be a Bad Idea (post increment is typically less efficient than preincrement and there is no real need to post increment the iterator in the code excerpt: it can as well be pre incremented at some other location).